# Google webmaster tools reporting entire nil subdomain linking to www domain, despite permanent redirect

Tags: seo, google-search-console, subdomain, duplicate-content

Looking in webmaster tools it is reported that I have a thousand of so inbound links from my root domain, domain.com, to www.domain.com. This is despite the fact I have a permanent redirect setup in nginx's conf file to www.

Obviously I don't want to be penalised for cross domain linking but how can I clear this mess up? To my knowledge the nil domain was never accessible so I don't know how google apparently indexed it.

Are there some particular steps I should take to resolve this? Is it likely that I am being penalised for duplicate content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set up [preferred domain in Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=44231)?

Comment: Well, the answer to that is 'kind of'. I needed moved the site to a new domain near the end of its development so set up a change of address request. The previous site was on a www subdomain and I requested the move to the new www. I am informed that due to this request that defining a preferred subdomain is not available to me. All in all it's a mess and given the site on the old domain had no particular ranking anyway I'm going to remove the request, set up the preferred subdomain and request a site reconsideration, in case I have been penalized. Thanks for your help.